# cassandra,elasticsearch and janusgraph setup on ubuntu 20.04 using kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, cassandra, janusgraph

I want to setup cassandra,elasticsearch and janusgraph  on ubuntu 20.04 using kubernetes.

can anyone suggest me links or provide me yaml file for setup?

i have a 3node Kubernetes cluster,1 master and 2 nodes,
i have installed 1.26.1 Kubernetes version

Comment: working on it..will update the status

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage the Operator to create these databases on Kubernetes.

**Operators** will manage and create the database for you.

**Elasticsearch** - https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elastic-cloud-kubernetes

**Cassandra** - https://github.com/instaclustr/cassandra-operator

**Janusgraph**  - https://github.com/IBM/janusgraph-operator

You can also leverage the helm chart available to setup database, mostly operators have helm chart for easy setup.

If you don't want to go with an operator you can directly install the helm also which will create the **Deployment**, **POD**, **services** for you with **PVC** and other required objects. The best practice will be to go with the **operator**.

Comment: the link for janusgraph asks for ibm login credentials.can i get a link which is opensource.Thank You!

Comment: yes better to use the opensource one, and pass necessary variables and config as per need. IBM one might be specific to their IBM env so yes better to check and go with opensource one. Also please feel to update the status of question if above answer your question or do upvote if found helpful.